# Endpoint listening error in WCF and windows phone

Tags: wcf, windows-phone-7

I am working on an windows phone,I made a WCF service.Throught i am uploading some data to server.Its working well in emulator but on phone some time application crashes due to wcf service error.Its giving me an error-"There was no endpoint listening at http:/MYSERVICE/Service1.svc that could accept the message.
This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details."
Sometime its working.

What may be the error and how can I solve it?

thanks

Comment: If sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't it can be an error with the Internet connection...